# opencv is not working with tensorflow virtualenv

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

i have installed tensorflow(virtualenv) on ubuntu(14.04) and installed opencv. opencv  is working with python tensorflow(virtualenv)  is working with python but unable to use tensorflow(virtualenv) and opencv together with python.

Answer (score 1):

openCV is also need to be there in virtualenv. You can create symbolic link of cv2.so inside virtualenv, if you have installed openCV globally.
For more details regarding creating symbolic link of openCV inside virtualenv,you can look into step 11 of following blog:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/